# For Loop Not Printing In Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Never coded in python before, so I am a total newbie. I just want to output some Clebsch-Gordan values to the screen and I thought of doing it via a for loop. However, the code does not print anything. I am using the PoweShell in Windows.

Here is what I did:

```
>>> from sympy.physics.quantum.cg import CG
>>> from sympy import S
>>> for i in range (2):
...     print(CG(1,1,1,1,2,S(i)).doit())
...
```

and then nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I am defining the for loop? Is it the way I am defining the CG coefficients?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Press ENTER once more.

Comment: Oh my God, I am such an idiot. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: No problem you just have to get used to writing code in the command prompt.

Comment: As long as you see that `...` it means the REPL is still waiting to see if you're done with that block of code.  You might want to have multiple lines of code in your `for` loop so it waits for a blank line to know you're done and run the loop.